# Android Setting textColor values as Global

Tags: android, styles, textcolor

I am doing some tutorials and I tried to chance the textColor. This works fine using the attribute in every Widget it the layout xml or the style attribute. But I was wondering if it is possible to define a global textColor, as far as I see it isn't.

I found a solution on these pages:

http://www.therealjoshua.com/2012/01/styling-android-with-defaults/

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/

In my little program I was using an EditText, RadioButton and Button. If I set the TextAppearance of every singel Widget with a style block with the parent @android:TextAppearance the widgets lost their other attributes. So I searched the style.xml and theme.xml and found a very short solution:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:color/primary_text_light">#FFFFFF</item>      
  </style>           
</resources>
```

Despite that in the theme.xml the predefined color is used

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.Button" parent="TextAppearance.Small.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light_nodisable</item>
</style>
```

My first question: Is there a way to overwrite the value of @android:color/primary_text_light_nodisable like I did with the other attributes?

Actually I think I solved the problem by myself:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/MyTextAppearanceButton</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/MyRadioButtonStyle</item>     
  </style>

  <style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTextAppearanceButton" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

So my second question is, if this is the correct way or is there a short way to change the color of the text globaly?

Althoug I think defining all this in xml is the cleanest method, I wanted to know if you suggest to manipulate this via the class methods?

Sorry I am pretty new to Java and Android programming and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a colors.xml under res/values and declare your global colours from here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="scheme">#007BB3</color>

    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="grey">#C1C1C1</color>  
</resources>
```

Comment: I tried this and set <color name="primary_text_light_nodisable">#FFFFFF</color> but it didn't overwrite the value of @android:color...

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clearer. You cannot overwrite the @android:color (as far as I know) however what you can do is set a colour within your colors.xml and then apply this to your View elements instead. Then when you want to update the colour you can change it in this single place rather than all across your layout files.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question, it wasn't about setting a color value it was about setting the color of all text in an app as correct and short as possible to one color. But I think you can use either the textColor attribute in every View or just redefine the style of every widget you use.